# Dreamweaver CS4 html5 syntax colouring problem?

Tags: syntax, html, colors, dreamweaver

My dreamweaver CS4 will not colour the syntax for HTML5 objects. However, I have downloaded an add-on through Adobe Exchange which allows automatic suggestions for HTML5. But I would love to have the syntax colouring. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which specific extension you installed, but I've tried:
HTML5 Pack for Dreamweaver CS3 and CS4
http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=2188522

With this installed, I get code coloring for HTML5 tags such as video and audio.

One note: If you have any CS5 application installed, you'll need to open the CS4 (or CS3) version of Extension Manager in order to install the extension. This is due to the latest install of Extension Manager registering itself as the handler for MXP files.